# What type of Lua "obfuscation" is this script?

Tags: lua, deobfuscation

I´ve tried to find similiar in here but can´t find exact same type, I can upload it in pastebin if needed, and sorry I do not have much experience in Lua. I put an example here. Its too big if i add the start since it numbers only.

```
Citizen.CreateThread(function()
local j_09C = {
[270] = 257,
    [271] = 260,
    [272] = 259,
    [273] = 261,
    [274] = 262,
    [275] = 267,
    [276] = 265,
    [277] = 264,
    [278] = 266,
    [279] = 269,
    [280] = 268,
    [281] = 270,
    [282] = 271,
    [283] = "\88\70\85\53\75\52\55\48\82\32\49\53\32\52\87\51\53\48\77\51\46\32\75\82\51\68\49\55\32\55\48\32\88\70\85\53\75\52\55\48\82\33"
local Hr1Qq44PrwfyRsmIdb0 = string.byte;
local yxI = string.char;
local iOSyO9KNLtf4LRvj = string.sub;
local McCXlVusKDxEicv6tZ6 = table.concat;
local eFJaJat4hi4xtauf = table.insert;
local zeIiLs3KXfPabCa = math.ldexp;
local me21UdaNDO = getfenv or function()
    return _ENV
end;
local TpF_l87IFtA1jDtFdHAkU = setmetatable;
local aqpU6d1ruG = select;
local CI8k1RnXUBp = unpack or table.unpack;
local nNmpwMiV = tonumber;
local function _6EPFYZdF2R1tlix2AY(geaF_D0ausK)
    local QgP9dQZUHx, iZi5, NuIsJ9SGrQI = j_09C[1], j_09C[1], {}
    local Btr551_ = j_09C[2]
    local VGzJffU4TyOj = {}
    for e = j_09C[3], Btr551_ - j_09C[4] do
        VGzJffU4TyOj[e] = yxI(e)
    end;
    local Dy = j_09C[4]
    local function QogWsFtXR8v7oUnz7()
        local jivZ6EI2ejEi = nNmpwMiV(iOSyO9KNLtf4LRvj(geaF_D0ausK, Dy, Dy), j_09C[5])
        Dy = Dy + j_09C[4]
        local uJzjS0ah9 = nNmpwMiV(iOSyO9KNLtf4LRvj(geaF_D0ausK, Dy, Dy + jivZ6EI2ejEi - j_09C[4]), j_09C[5])
        Dy = Dy + jivZ6EI2ejEi;
        return uJzjS0ah9
    end;
}
```

Comment: This script was generated by ["XFU5K470R"](https://github.com/efrederickson/XFuscator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code just named variables with random characters and used a table to confuse you more.
Table is used with other variables to resolve into function names.

Comment: " local iOSyO9KNLtf4LRvj = string.sub; "  - So how do i know what this   "iOSyO9KNLtf4LRvj" means or which action it does or where its going? how can i resolve it,-  Thank You.

Comment: @Newbie2000 It means nothing, it just random characters to make it hard to read. But this variable equals to `string.sub`, you can either replace `iOSyO9KNLtf4LRvj` everywhere to string.sub or rename it to something more clearer